# Como colocar um fundo num setup nsis?

Tags: nsis, setup

Estou a fazer um `setup.exe` para uma aplicação com a ajuda do [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) e estou a compilar o mesmo em ubuntu.

Queria agora personalizar o setup para que aparecesse com imagem de fundo tipo este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é que eu posso colocar uma imagem no *setup* com o [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)?

Comment: Não consigo testar, mas dê uma olhada [nestes](https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-291816.html) [links](https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-337445.html).

Comment: Obrigado @utluiz vou experimentar...